# What is "discrete graphics configuration" and how do I avoid it?

Tags: bsod, overheating, dell-xps

I read [here](https://www.dell.com/support/article/il/en/ildhs1/sln311210/xps-9570-precision-5530-blue-screen-freezing-random-shutdown-system-heat-issue?lang=en) that "XPS 9570/Precision 5530 may demonstrate BSOD(blue screen)/freezing/random shutdown/system heat issue during graphichs heavy loading condition. This happens on XPS 9570/Precision 5530 with **discrete graphics configuration** only."

What is this "discrete graphics configuration" thing, and how can I disable it (from XPS 9570) in order to avoid the risk of over-heating?

Comment: The XPS 9570 has a dedicated GPU and an integrated GPU, discrete graphics configuration, would mean your device is only using the dedicated GPU.  You can enable the integrated GPU within the XPS 9570's firmware settings.  However, I can guarantee you that if you currently have an overheating issue, you will still have an overheating issue even if you enable the integrated GPU.  I would submit an answer, but I don't have a Dell system to look at, to write down the steps to enable/disable the integrated GPU.  Dell support has documentation I am sure.

Comment: The article you linked to, indicates the solution to your problem, is to upgrade the firmware.  Why have you not done that?  It's also possible the article means, the systems don't have an iGPU, in which case this only happens when the system has a dGPU.  Solution is the same, upgrade the firmware, and the system will stop crashing

Comment: Who said I have not done that? I just want to be on the safe side and not get into this problem in the first place.

Comment: Those systems have dozens of configurations.  You have not supplied us with information to determine, if that article, even applies to your system's configuration.  If you don't have a discrete GPU installed, then the article does not apply to your system.  If your willing to provide your system configuration, I will be happy, to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the manual for your device and find out how to start up into BIOS. It's usually done by pressing F10 or F12 soon after the machine starts. Once inside the BIOS, you can look around for the specific graphics settings.  Sorry I can't be more specific without diving into the specific computer, version of the BIOS, version of the graphics firmware, etc.